# Rounding numbers in a table built with a macro

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, pgfmath

I would like to round the decimal places in the generated table in the following code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

  \tikzset{fixed point arithmetic}
  \tikzmath{
    function printfib(\i,\f){print {$f_{\i} = \f$\newline};};
    function sequencia(\n) {
      real \a, \x, \e;
      real \S;
      \a = 2;
      \x = 0; 
        for \i in {1,...,\n}{
          \x = 0.5*(6 + \x);
          \e = abs(6-\x);
        };
      return {\x};
    };
    int \i;
    real \seq;
    real \erro;
    for \i in {1,...,20}{
      \seq{\i}=sequencia(\i);
       \erro{\i}=abs(6-sequencia(\i));
    };
  }

\def\tmp{$n$ & $f(n)$ & $|erro|$\\ \midrule}%
\edef\iloop{0}%
\loop
\edef\iloop{\the\numexpr\iloop+1}%
\xappto\tmp{$\iloop$ & $\seq{\iloop}$ & $\erro{\iloop}$}  %
\gappto\tmp{\\}%
\ifnum\iloop<20\repeat

\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
\toprule
\tmp
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

whose output is the following:

[image]

There is a way to generate this table with less decimal places?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are loading `xfp`, you could use it for this.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

  \tikzset{fixed point arithmetic}
  \tikzmath{
    function printfib(\i,\f){print {$f_{\i} = \f$\newline};};
    function sequencia(\n) {
      real \a, \x, \e;
      real \S;
      \a = 2;
      \x = 0; 
        for \i in {1,...,\n}{
          \x = 0.5*(6 + \x);
          \e = abs(6-\x);
        };
      return {\x};
    };
    int \i;
    real \seq;
    real \erro;
    for \i in {1,...,20}{
      \seq{\i}=sequencia(\i);
       \erro{\i}=abs(6-sequencia(\i));
    };
  }

\def\tmp{$n$ & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{$f(n)$} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{$|erro|$}\\ \midrule}%
\edef\iloop{0}%
\loop
\edef\iloop{\the\numexpr\iloop+1}%
\xappto\tmp{$\iloop$ & $\fpeval{round(\seq{\iloop},6)}$ & $\fpeval{round(\erro{\iloop},6)}$}  %
\gappto\tmp{\\}%
\ifnum\iloop<20\repeat

\begin{tabular}{c|l|l}
\toprule
\tmp
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Note that you can use `siunitx` with the `S` column to align expressions at the dot and so on, but here this is not necessary at this point.

Obviously you can also do without `xfp`. In a way this is more elegant or convenient since you can control everything with pgf keys:

```
 \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=5}
```

and also because there are a bit more and better documented options. It is also less elegant because you have to add a `\noexpand`. So, as almost always, it is a matter of taste what is better.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fp}
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

  \tikzset{fixed point arithmetic}
  \tikzmath{
    function printfib(\i,\f){print {$f_{\i} = \f$\newline};};
    function sequencia(\n) {
      real \a, \x, \e;
      real \S;
      \a = 2;
      \x = 0; 
        for \i in {1,...,\n}{
          \x = 0.5*(6 + \x);
          \e = abs(6-\x);
        };
      return {\x};
    };
    int \i;
    real \seq;
    real \erro;
    for \i in {1,...,20}{
      \seq{\i}=sequencia(\i);
       \erro{\i}=abs(6-sequencia(\i));
    };
  }

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=5}%
\def\tmp{$n$ & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{$f(n)$} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{$|erro|$}\\ \midrule}%
\edef\iloop{0}%
\loop
\edef\iloop{\the\numexpr\iloop+1}%
\xappto\tmp{$\iloop$ & $\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber{\seq{\iloop}}$ & 
    $\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber{\erro{\iloop}}$}  %
\gappto\tmp{\\}%
\ifnum\iloop<20\repeat

\begin{tabular}{c|l|l}
\toprule
\tmp
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]